# How to access parent ViewModel property from child ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ParentViewModel with a property

```
class ParentViewModel : BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _text = "";

    public string Text //the property
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }

    ChildViewModel _childViewModel;

    public ParentViewModel()
    {
        _childViewModel = new ChildViewModel(Text);
    }
```

and ChildViewModel from which I want to access the parents "Text" property to set it from inside ChildViewModel and I tried this

```
class ChildViewModel : BaseObservableObject
{

    public string _text { get; set; }

    public ParentViewModel(string Text)
    {
        _text = Text;

        _text += "some text to test if it changes the Text of the parent"; //how I tried to set it
    }
```

But the reason it does not work is because strings in c# are immutable.I then tried to send the parent object as a constructor parameter which worked but I did not want to send the whole parent as a constructor parameter. This is how I was able to set the parents property from inside child

```
parentViewModel.Text += "some text";
```

EDIT : I was trying access a parent VM property from its child VM to set it from inside the child and have it changed in the parent. I ended up learning about the Mediator patters which is a way of storing actions and accessing them from wherever you are trying to do so.

Comment: Show your code, this is just a property getter/setter, show the code that you've tried.

Comment: The reason why the parameter does not change is that strings are immutable, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/

Comment: @Charleh I added some code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For communication between ViewModels, I would suggest some implementation of Messenger pattern as contained in many MVVM frameworks, for example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/june/mvvm-the-mvvm-light-messenger-in-depth

As a bit dirty solution, you could pass an `Action` instead of the string property
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-5.0

```
public ChildViewModel(Action<string> updateText)
{
    updateText("my new value")
}
```

and the creation of ChildViewModel in parent:

```
new ChildViewModel(x => Text = x);
```

Comment: This worked, thank you, I will check the messenger pattern for sure